# How to read multiple data sets, and create a single dataframe with a year column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I would like to read multiple data sets and combine them into a single Pandas dataframe with a year column.

My sample data sets include `newyork2000.txt`, `newyork2001.txt`, `newyork2002.txt`.

Each data set contains `'address'` and `'price'`.

Below is the `newyork2000.txt`:

```
253 XXX st, 150000
2567 YYY st, 200000
...
3896 ZZZ rd, 350000
```

My final single dataframe should look like this:

```
year address      price
2000 253 XXX st   150000
2000 2567 YYY st  200000
...
2000 3896 ZZZ rd  350000
...
2002 789 XYZ ave  450000
```

So, I need to combine all data sets, create the year column, and name the columns.

Here is my code to create a single dataframe:

```
years=[2000,2001,2002]
df=[]
for i years:
    df.append(pd.read_csv("newyork" + str(i) + ".txt", header=None))
dfs=pd.concat(df)
```

But, I could not create the year column and name the columns. Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It is preferred to programmatically extract the `year` from the filename, than to manually create a `list` of years.
- Use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) with [`.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) to find the files, use the [`.stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) method to extract the filename, and then slice the `year` from the stem, with `[-4:]`, providing the names of the files are consistent, with the `year` as the last 4 characters of the filename.

  - The `.stem` method will extract the final path component (e.g. `'newyork2000'`), without its suffix (e.g. `'.txt'`)
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) to add the `'year'` column to a specific location in the dataframe. This method inserts the column inplace, so do not use `x = x.insert(...)`,

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

# set the file path
file_path = Path('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/data/example')

# find your files
files = file_path.glob('newyork*.txt')

# create a list of dataframes
df_list = list()

for f in files:
    # extract year from filename, by slicing the last four characters off the stem
    year = (f.stem)[-4:]
    
    # read the file and add column names
    x = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, names=['address', 'price'])
    
    # add a year column at index 0; use int(year) if the year should be an int, otherwise use only year
    x.insert(0, 'year', int(year))
    
    # append to the list
    df_list.append(x)
    
# create one dataframe from the list of dataframes
df = pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### Result

```
 year      address   price
 2000   253 XXX st  150000
 2000  2567 YYY st  200000
 2000  3896 ZZZ rd  350000
 2001  456 XYZ ave  650000
 2002  789 XYZ ave  450000
```

#### Sample data files

- `'newyork2000.txt'`

```
253 XXX st, 150000
2567 YYY st, 200000
3896 ZZZ rd, 350000
```

- `'newyork2001.txt'`

```
456 XYZ ave, 650000
```

- `'newyour2002.txt'`

```
789 XYZ ave, 450000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the files first, then insert the columns corresponding to years, and then concatenate them:

```py
import pandas as pd

years = [2000,2001,2002]

# Read all CSV files
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f"newyork{year}.txt", header=None) for year in years]

# Insert column in the beginning
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
   df.insert(0, 'year', years[i])

# Concatenate all
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```